# How to assert/verify tests using Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, testing

How would I check to see if the correct text was input into the text box?

My code is:

```
element = driver.find_element :id => "gmail-sign-in"
element.click

element = driver.find_element :id => "Email"
element.send_keys "exampletestemail2903@gmail.com"


input = wait.until {
  element = driver.find_element :id => "Email"
  element if element.displayed?
}
input.send_keys("exampletestemail2903@gmail.com")
if input == "exampletestemail2903@gmail.com"
  puts 'Correct Input'
else
  puts 'Wong Input'
end
```

For example, I have this to check if the input text is correct, however, it prints the `else` message even though the input is correct.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: What is assigned to the variable `input` before it enters the `if/else` statement?  If it's not "exampletestemail2903@gmail.com", it will be "Wong".

Comment: Unsure what you mean? I just basically want to check that the email address entered using sendkeys is correct.

Comment: You are assigning to a`input` variable here: `input = wait.until {
... }`.  When you enter the `if/else` statement, what is the value of `input`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We're not concerned about your "newbieness", we just want you to do your due-diligence prior to asking and research and try, a lot, then write a well thought-out question. I'd recommend you check your grammar and spelling as those are important. It will help you to read http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 along with "[mcve]".

Comment: Value that is input: exampletestemail2903@gmail.com

Comment: Or how do I assert that the value that has been inputted using sendkeys is the correct input value?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to verify that send_keys is working correctly. That is unless there is some other action that could change the field you are entering text into after the text has been entered.
As for the reason that your if block is always going to the else is that you are comparing an element to a string. The if block should be changed to the following to compare a string to a string:

```
if input.text == "exampletestemail2903@gmail.com"
```

That should fix the if block to be functioning as you expect.

Comment: This did not work it still prints the else block to the console. Wonder why checking the inputted text is so difficult !

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify text in textbox to assert its value

```
element = driver.find_element :id => "gmail-sign-in"
element.click

element = driver.find_element :id => "Email"
element.send_keys "exampletestemail2903@gmail.com"


input = wait.until {
  element = driver.find_element :id => "Email"
  element if element.displayed?
}
input.send_keys("exampletestemail2903@gmail.com")
if input.text == "exampletestemail2903@gmail.com"
  puts 'Correct Input'
else
  puts 'Wong Input'
end
```

Hope this Helps :)

Comment: It still prints 'Wrong Input' to the console? Thanks for assistant

Comment: Can you try with
if element.text == "exampletestemail2903@gmail.com"
Instead of
if input.text == "exampletestemail2903@gmail.com"
And confirm me if this helps you?

Comment: I will try this Tonight. Thanks